# Order by field with lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, lambda, listobject

I am trying to order a list of lists by one of the fields.

I have two lists in one grouped list. The first contains the Id, the second contains the count. I was successfully able to group the list of lists by Id and reformat it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GroupedListofLists.Count; i++)
            {
                tempo_Id.Add(GroupedListofLists[i][0]);
                tempo_count.Add(GroupedListofLists[i][1]);
            }

GroupedListofLists.Clear();
GroupedListofLists.Add(tempo_Id);
GroupedListofLists.Add(tempo_count);
```

If I print out the GroupedListofLists I will have distinct Ids (GroupedListofLists[0]) each with their count in the second(GroupedListofLists [1]).

Now when I try to sort this list with lambda expression I have a problem. I tried these two methods:

```
GroupedlistofLists.Sort( (a, b) =>  Convert.ToDouble(a[idx]).CompareTo(Convert.ToDouble(b[idx])));
```

AND

```
GroupedlistofLists = GroupedlistofLists.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDouble(x[idx])).ToList();
```

A problem arises.

In the first method no matter what values I used for the variable 'idx', a will be assigned the values of GroupedListofLists[0] and b the values of GroupedListofLists[1].

In the second, no matter what values I use for the variable 'idx' (0 or 1), x will always contain the values for GroupedListofLists[0]. Which are the Id value and I need to sort them by Count, so GroupedListofLists[1].

I hope I was clear.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide code sample with part where you group, and would be great if you will in list and provide class definition.

Comment: What exactly is this `list`? Personally I think it'd be better to write and call an actual compare method here... then you control completely what happens.

Comment: Hello I edited so it's clearer, list was actually GroupedListofLists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exacly know what you're trying to do. But i'll do a guess:

```
// Build some List you want to sort
List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "3", "1", "2" };
// Sort the List
myList = myList.OrderBy(a => Convert.ToDouble(a));
```

The Lambda-Expression in OrderBy needs to select a value which will be ordered in default manner. The Lambda-Expression will be run for every item in your list. The results will be used as order-key. you don't need any index.
Sort can be used so sort complex types.

Better version should work on a List with correct class and type. A Convert within a lambda-expression should be avoided!

```
// Some example-class with multiple properties
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

// Some test-data
List<MyItem> myList = new List<MyItem>()
{
    new MyItem() { Name = "One", Value = 1 },
    new MyItem() { Name = "Three", Value = 3 },
    new MyItem() { Name = "Two", Value = 2 }
}

// select the value you want to use for ordering the list.
myList = myList.OrderBy(item => item.Value);

// Expected output: 1, 2, 3
foreach(MyItem item in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value + ", " + item.Name);
}

// Expected output: 3, 2, 1
myList = myList.OrderBy(item => item.Name);

foreach(MyItem item in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value + ", " + item.Name);
}
```

(I got no Visual Studio installed, so check for typos ;))

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer but I'm working with nested lists. This doesn't work.